# PFFile Retrieve Access Denied

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I had a parse database and I needed to copy and move it to another place. Now I can not reach PFFiles that I uploaded to the first database.
How can i fix this?

edit :

```
PFFile *posterFile = [[eventList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"poster"];
        [posterFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {}];
```

is how I get my pffile.

The problem is DB is copied to another application created through dashboard and pffiles as i understand has only view privilege for its own application. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Show us your code/provide more detail please.

Comment: added some codes and more information as edit.